# Fresco does not support disc cache for local photos which stored in disc

Tags: fresco

Fresco does not support disc cache for local images which stored in disc memory,but only support for images from network.
May this feature be fixed in the future.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? If the photo is already locally stored on the disk, it does not make sense to store the same image a second time on disk since it's already there.

Comment: App need to show large amounts of images from local disc memory. We used recycleview and show 16 images in one page .But original images may be too large and cost much time to load.so we hope to use  small resized images from disc cache after it used to be loaded.it will save much time and  make good experience.Actually , glide has this feature.In comparison demo,we can see,when load local images,glide cost less time than fresco as it has disc cache.